# Login as a customer from custom table in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, controllers, login, customer-account

I want to login with custom field from custom table in magento 1.9, how to manage session,cookies and every default functionality for custom login user.Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide details. Why do you want a new database table?

Comment: **I want create 4 ** user type for custom magento site, three 3 pre-defined by magento . i want add  1 more user type . who has same privilege as above magento pre-defined user type have. 4th user can do login and checkout  as same process.. i think its clarify the question.@Black

Comment: Do you mean customer group? You can create in backend

Comment: i created a custom registration form for 4th user type and inserting into custom table  and creating loginpost controller for login 4th user (working) but session is not working . how to manage the session and all attributes / functionality???

Comment: 4th user type?? What is 1th, 2nd and 3th?

Comment: 1: General 2:Retailers 3:Corporate 4th: Store Operator